# What the error in writing this equation by latex?

Tags: equations, unicode

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(\lambda x+(1−\lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x)+(1−\lambda)f(y)
\end{eqnarray*}
```

What the error in writing  this equation by latex?

the oregenal equation

Comment: please always post a complete small document that produces the error and show the error you got. `eqnarray`  should have more than one row, and each row should have two `&` but not doing that does not generate an error, just bad output.

Comment: @Mico... Actually for Greeks the typo is inside `\lambda` and not the opposite...  So, it is a bug in the name... But you are right.

Comment: @Mico also it's a typo added since I posted my answer, otherwise the error I showed would be different, I'll revert :(

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(q x+(1−\lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x)+(1−\lambda)f(y)
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character − (U+2212)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 f(q x+(1−
               \lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x)+(1−\lambda)f(y)
?
```

use an ascii minus sign `-` not −

Also you should use `\[...\]` not `eqnarray*` for a single line equation with no alignment points.

Comment: thanks a lot it run with me ...............................................................................................................thanks

Comment: @HM If this response answers your question, could you accept it? (Press the green checkbox next to the voting buttons to do that.)